# is redirecting from one jsp to another jsp bad practice? And if yes why?

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, servlets, forward

I just have started to learn java web programming and on several websites and resources I have read that redirecting from one JSP to another is bad practice. For instance, my code is something like this:

```
<form>
<body>
<button name="nameButton">Button</button>
<%
String stringButton = request.getParameter("nameButton");
if(stringButton != null){
response.sendRedirect("anotherJSPFile.jsp");
}
%>
</body>
</form>
```

It is working fine, but I wouldn't like to seem amateur and learn better way so any suggestion?

Comment: The problem is actually including java code in you JSP files.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files  You should try to follow the MVC paradigm whereby JSP is only there for displaying and the **logic** is done in your `Controller` being a servlet.

Comment: For that matter, JSP has a lot of shortcomings that template systems like Thymeleaf don't, and I recommend against it for new projects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Writing Java code inside JSP file in not good practice. Move the redirection logic to servelt. Follow some standard design patterns like MVC and segregate the Model, View, Controller.

It will be easy to maintain in future.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your answer. After a period of time I did understood what you meant.